# TestNG java.net.SocketException

Tags: exception, testng, socketexception

I'm attempting to run TestNG tests but I keep getting a `java.net.SocketException`. Other forums state that this is a known issue for users running TestNG 6.4 and greater on IDEA but I am using Eclipse. I tried reinstalling TestNG to eclipse but that did not help. Furthermore TestNG is failing to report which tests have passed and which have failed. Below is the code that is causing this Exception and notice that the test method is actually empty.

```
public class AdminUITest extends AccountingTS{

@BeforeClass
public void oneTimeSetUp() {

}

@AfterClass
public void oneTimeTearDown(){
driver.quit();
//      closeJSchSessions();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Method method){
resetStep();
printStep("TEST CASE >>> "+method.getName());
}
@Test
public void test()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this in Eclipse by clicking on Windows>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs>Edit and changing the JRE Home to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed TestNG from eclipse then go to your project properties, click TestNG and uncheck **Use project TestNG jar**.

Please don't include TestNG jar explicitly in your project's build path, doing so lead to confusion and exception.

[image]